# ajax retorna sempre em branco

Tags: php, ajax

Meu problema é o seguinte tenho um campo de busca que traz dados em uma tabela via ajax, nesta tabela tem botões para que o usúario possa obtar mais informações sobre os dados que são buscados, nesses botões estou tentando chamar essa segunda informação também via ajax o problema é que o segundo ajax esta retornando sempre em branco não sei oq acontence.

esta é a tabela, o onclick vai para função mostrar fase que vou postar logo em baixo.

```
<td>'.$exf_obj->nom_req.'</td>  
                          <td>'.$reg['descricao'].'</td>                          
                          <td>'.$reg['dtfase'].'</td>                         
                          <td>'.$exf_obj->n_proce.'</td>
                          <input type="hidden" value='.$reg['sql_rowid'].' id="id_fase">
                          <td><a href="" onclick="return mostrar_fase()" class="tiny button">Mostrar mais</a></td>                                        
                          <td><a href="Busca/mostrar/'.$reg['sql_rowid'] .'" class="tiny button">Mostrar mais</a></td>                                        
                          </tr>';
```

A função do ajax é essa

```
function mostrar_fase(){
ajax = xmlhttp();
id_fase = document.getElementById('id_fase').value; 
if(ajax)
{       
    ajax.open("POST",'http://localhost/sac/Ajax/mostrar_fase/' + id_fase, true);
    alert(ajax.responseText);
     ajax.onreadystatechange = function() 
    {       
        if (ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200)             
        {       

            document.getElementById("tabela").innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
        }
    }
    ajax.send(); 
}
}


case 'mostrar_fase':
            echo 'chega';
            $id_fase = Sistema::getKey();
            Connection::open();
            $dados_fase = Connection::select("select * from fases01 where sql_rowid = '".$id_fase."'");
            $reg_fase = $dados_fase->fetchObject();
            $dados_exf = Connection::select("select * from arq_exf where num_pro = '".$reg_fase->processo."'");
            $reg_exf = $dados_exf->fetchObject();
            $html = $html = new Html();
            $nova = $html->carregar('view/mostrar.html');
            $nova = str_replace('#NOME#', $reg_exf->nom_req, $nova);
            $nova = str_replace('#DESCRICAO#', $reg_fase->descricao, $nova);
            echo $nova; 
            break;
```

o primeiro codigo de ajax esta praticamente igual a esse que postei apenas difere o link e a variavel e o primeiro funciona de maneira correta. Espero ter sido claro em minha pergunta. Obrigado desde ja.

Comment: Quando acessa o link do ajax manualmente aparece algum erro?

Comment: não, quando acessa o link manualmente retorna oq eu preciso. Uma duvida que tenho se é possível usar um ajax logo após outro.

Comment: Poste o código de `xmlhttp`.